# UDP listener seems to hang after being closed until another packet is being received

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

While practicing a bit on concurrency with go, I faced a problem.

I am making a dns filtering server, it receives a dns packet, and act as a recursive server with caching and its own records.

Starting the server works all great, but when I try to close the listener to shut the server down, it just hangs until there is another packet arriving.

So what I have been trying to do is run another anonymous function that receives a message from a channel, close the listener, clear cache and exit from the server goroutine.

Related code:

```
func StartDNSServer(recursiveServer, ip string, port int, ch chan bool) {
    stopChn := make(chan bool)
    //Listen on UDP Port
    addr := net.UDPAddr{
        Port: port,
        IP:   net.ParseIP(ip),
    }
    fmt.Println("[*] Starting dns server...")
    u, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &addr)

    //u.ReadFrom is a blocking command, so if we try to stop the dns server it wont detect the data in ch until there is a new dns packet.
    // anonymous function to close the udp listener to realease the blocking.
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-ch:
            stopChn <- false
            u.Close()
        }
    }()
    defer u.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("Could not listen on given port, maybe another application is using it?")
    }
    fmt.Println("[*] Started!")
    // Wait to get request on that port
    for {
        select {
        case <-stopChn:
            fmt.Println("[*] Deleting records from cache.")
            Cache.DeleteExpired()
            fmt.Println("[*] Stopping dns server")
            runtime.Goexit()
        default:
            tmp := make([]byte, 1024)
            _, addr, _ := u.ReadFrom(tmp)
            clientAddr := addr
            packet := gopacket.NewPacket(tmp, layers.LayerTypeDNS, gopacket.Default)
            dnsPacket := packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeDNS)
            tcp, _ := dnsPacket.(*layers.DNS)
            go handleDNS(u, clientAddr, tcp, recursiveServer)
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

From what I managed to get, the select statement under the infinite for loop is entering the default section, and then waiting for a packet, after that its handling the packet, it is "noticing" that the stopChn has received a signal, and shutting down.

So if this is really the case, I then tried to change the `stopChn := make(chan bool)` into a buffered channel `stopChn := make(chan bool, 1)`.

Now it really does trigger the desired action immediately, but panics with the error:

> panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
>
> goroutine 16 [running]:
> */C*/Users/moti_/OneDrive/Desktop/GoDNSFilter/internals/dnsserver.handleDNS(0xc000006660,
> 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0001ea180, 0xa98f34, 0x7)
> C:/Users/moti_/OneDrive/Desktop/GoDNSFilter/internals/dnsserver/utils.go:32
> +0x75b created by */C*/Users/moti_/OneDrive/Desktop/GoDNSFilter/internals/dnsserver.StartDNSServer
> C:/Users/moti_/OneDrive/Desktop/GoDNSFilter/internals/dnsserver/utils.go:151
> +0x2be

I looked for it online, and some answers said that I might be sending too many signals into the stopChn but it would be blocking, not panicking..

Not sure if I am approaching this correctly, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i dont think the call to close is blocking. I think that within your select you are missing a return statement in the stopChn case. Your program receive a close signal on ch (?), closes the socket *and* keeps reading on it, until some timeout occurs. Note that `runtime.Goexit` does not exit the program. you normally dont need that much complex code to exit.

Comment: @mh-cbon thanks for the reply.
Its not the call to stop that is blocking, it is the ReadFrom, which is why I needed the anonymous function, because I cannot close one goroutine from another, so I close the server routine from the anonymous one.
I do agree it shouldn't be so complex, which is why I think I approach this incorrectly..

Comment: should look like this https://play.golang.org/p/xA6abDP4oah but you still need to synchronize the call to close with handleDNS, I suppose that function writes on the socket. If you want graceful shutdown you can make use of a waitgroup to prevent closing of the socket before the remaining input requests were answered.

Comment: as soon as you returned you wont read on the socket, thus dont block on read.

Comment: maybe something like this https://play.golang.org/p/uM2D8AdzXMN the reads are cmpletely aync. Their routine exits as soon as the signal is sent. It waits for remaining writes to close the socket and exit.

Comment: @mh-cbon I have tried doing so now, and same situation happens.
The goroutine waits for the `ReadFrom` to finish, before it can continue with the infinite for loop.
The only way to unblock the `ReadFrom` call is to call `u.Close()` but then i get the error specified above.

Comment: though there is always a situation where one read will block the loop.

Comment: i dont know for that error, its incomplete.

Comment: @mh-cbon edited with complete stack trace if thats what you meant?

Comment: yes. I guess that is because you are not checking for errors from ReadFrom. Also, you should make use of the returned n.

Comment: this version might still block on a read when the exit sequence begins https://play.golang.org/p/uFbdBJck__S

Comment: @mh-cbon managed to solve it. I changed the channel to a buffered one, and handled the error that is thrown while closing the listener while still listening. 
I still need to use n from `ReadFrom` and handle the error with error type and not string, but it was just for testing.
Thank you for your help!
https://play.golang.org/p/Q-4Nd22dzya

Answer (score 0):

So, After @mh-cbon helped me a lot, heres the solution if any one ever gonna face the same problem.
As said before, I cannot close one goroutine from another, so I had to use 2 channels, one for the not blocked goroutine, which will close the listener and then clear out cache and all.
Still got to compare error with error vars, but for solution its enough for now.

```
func StartDNSServer(recursiveServer, ip string, port int, ch chan bool) {
    //Listen on UDP Port
    addr := net.UDPAddr{
        Port: port,
        IP:   net.ParseIP(ip),
    }
    fmt.Println("[*] Starting dns server...")
    u, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &addr)

    //u.ReadFrom is a blocking command, so if we try to stop the dns server it wont detect the data in ch until there is a new dns packet.
    // anonymous function to close the udp listener to realease the blocking.
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-ch:
            u.Close()
        }
    }()
    defer u.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("Could not listen on given port, maybe another application is using it?")
    }
    fmt.Println("[*] Started!")
    // Wait to get request on that port
    for {
        tmp := make([]byte, 1024)
        _, addr, err := u.ReadFrom(tmp)
        if err != nil {
            if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "use of closed network connection") {
                fmt.Println("[*] Deleting records from cache.")
                Cache.DeleteExpired()
                fmt.Println("[*] Stopping dns server")
                return

            }
            clientAddr := addr
            packet := gopacket.NewPacket(tmp, layers.LayerTypeDNS, gopacket.Default)
            dnsPacket := packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeDNS)
            tcp, _ := dnsPacket.(*layers.DNS)
            go handleDNS(u, clientAddr, tcp, recursiveServer)
            continue
        }
    }
}
```